# MongoDB ISODate being returned as empty array in JSON output, PHP Web Application

Tags: php, mongodb, date, datetime, aggregation-framework

I'm storing my data with ISODate objects in MongoDB:

```
"datetime" : ISODate("2016-10-03T14:00:00.000+0000")
```

My aggregation pipeline function performs various matching with $lte and $gte which appear to be working correctly and returning data. However, when inspecting my output as JSON, I'm getting the following results:

```
[
  {
    "_id": "london_10:2016-10-05 12",
    "data": {
      "voltage_a": 0.008888,
      "voltage_b": 0.008888,
      "voltage_c": 0.008888,
      "current_a": 0.008888,
      "current_b": 0.008888,
      "current_c": 0.008888,
      "current_n": 0.008888,
      "active_power_a": 5.6,
      "active_power_b": 5.6,
      "active_power_c": 5.6,
      "reactive_power_a": 0.8888,
      "reactive_power_b": 0,
      "reactive_power_c": 0,
      "total_active_power": 168,
      "datetime": {

      }
    }
  }
]
```

For some reason, the datetime is being output as an empty array. Would it be that the aggregation pipeline needs to include something in the $project stage that outputs the date object in string format?

Update: aggregation pipeline is below

```
  $pipeline = [
      [
        '$match' => [
          '_id' => $regex,
          'datehour' => [ '$gte' => $UTCdatehourFrom, '$lte' => $UTCdatehourTo ]
        ]
      ],
      [
        '$unwind' => '$data'
      ],
      [
        '$match' => [
          'data.datetime' => [ '$gte' => $UTCdatetimeFrom,
                               '$lte' => $UTCdatetimeTo]
        ]
      ],
      [
        '$sort' => [
          'data.datetime' => -1
        ]
      ],
      [
        '$project' => [
          'data' => '$data',
          '_id' => -1
        ]
      ]
    ];
```

Comment: Where is the aggregation pipeline code in question?

Comment: show the code please ?

Comment: added the pipeline. Let me know if you need further info, but I think the $UTCdatetime variables are working otherwise I'd have nothing coming out of the pipeline, right?